# Create URLs from Database

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, replace

I am trying to create clean URLs from information entered by the user. I have this in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/$ /records.php [QSA,L]
```

This works great for when going to an address like so: example.com/blah/. What I have it doing is printing all records of category "blah" or whatever else the user enters (or I link to). The problem comes in when a user enters and stores a category with a space. I want to keep the integrity of the category with the space, but I also need to create a URL friendly version of the category. I'm linking to the categories like so:

```
$nospace = str_replace(" ", "-", $row['category']) ; 
echo "<a href=/".$nospace."/>" . $nospace . "</a>";
```

The problem comes in when you arrive at the destination URL. If the category has a space, but I'm linking to a category with a -, I naturally don't get anything from that category. It doesn't exist.

How can I keep the space in the category name, but at the same time be able to create a URL friendly category name and link to it?

Answer (score 0):

php (which is what it looks like you are using) supports `urlencode` and `urldecode` You can build your links with url encoded categories, and then on the other end url decode them.  =)

```
echo '<a href="/'.urlencode($row['category']).'">'.$row['category']."</a>";
```

Comment: That's great! The only issue is that the urlencode adds a + between spaces instead of a -. How can I change that?

Comment: Well, if you want reliable encoding-decoding you should just let `urlencode` do it's thing. Is it essential that you use hypens? If so, `str_replace('+','-',urlencode($row['category']))` to encode, and then `urldecode(str_replace('+','-',$_GET['category']))`